# wire custom plugin with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I've written a plugin for ES 5.x.x with all components: Plugin, Factory, Provider, Analyzer, Filter (the filter has the important logic).
I tested it with

```
GET index/_analyze?analyzer=my_plugin_name
```

and it works fine.
now I want to integrate it with ES through

```
PUT index/_settings -d @settings.json
```

but receiving and error

> ```
> "caused_by" : {
>   "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
>   "reason" : "Unknown filter type [MyPluginFactory class name: com.a.b.c.plugin.MyPluginFactory] for [my_filter]
> ```

what is the correct way for ES to find my filter? in settings.json I have set

```
"type" : "com.a.b.c.plugin.MyPluginFactory"
```

is this how it should work? here's the complete settings.json:

```
 {   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
       "filter": {
         "my_filter" : {
           "type" : "com.a.b.c.plugin.MyPluginFactory"
         }
       },
       "analyzer": {
         "my_analyser": {
           "tokenizer": "standard",
           "filter": [
             "my_filter"
           ]}}}}}
```

the plugin is installed via

> elasticsearch-plugin install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, blast.. in my Plugin class I had implemented getAnalyzers(), but it looks like in order to be able to set up a filter, getTokenFilters() has to be implemented as well